# How to call parametrized stored procedure from LINQ (Entity Framework)

Tags: linq

Is there any way i can call parametrized stored procedure from LINQ (Entity Framework). It would be nice if u can share an example

Comment: what's the specific problem? Otherwise check the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896334.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following link

[Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: This is about LINQ-to-SQL. The question explicitly states Entity Framework.